# firefox addon using sdk pagemod seems not have access to all dom

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I was writing some add-on in firefox using the add-on sdk, I've noticed that my add-on didn't work properly in some pages like *google*.

Here is a sample code.

lib/main.js

```
var pageMod = require('sdk/page-mod');
var data = require('sdk/self').data;

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*.com",
    contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
    contentScriptFile: [data.url('jquery-1.11.0.min.js'),
                        data.url('detecter.js')]        
});
```

data/detecter.js

```
$('*').css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

cfx run to launch, then I type something in google here is the result:

[image]

as you can see not everything is yellow, plus I can change those elements background easily using the inspector. I can't see how I can do this using just my add-on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying, the way you are doing, each DOM element is not the best way. And if the document changes dynamically like Google does with its search result pages would drive you to try to deal with [DOM mutation events and observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) in order to add the wished CSS styles to the new recently created elements. Too complex.

One way to get the results you want, is to modify your **data/detecter.js** file to just inject a CSS file with the rules you need, something like:

```
var customStyles = document.createElement('style'); 
customStyles.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
   '* { background-color: yellow'}'
));
document.documentElement.insertBefore(customStyles);
```

This way, you don't need to deal with observers or do trickier things.

Another approach, is using **contentStyle** attribute of PageMod, the way it is described in [Modifying Web Pages Based on URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Modifying_Web_Pages_Based_on_URL#Injecting_CSS) tutorial in MDN. This is an experimental feature but it seems to be the simplest way, since you will only need to write the css rules, neither jquery nor a custom javascript is needed. Take a look:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod").PageMod({
    include: "*.com",
    contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
    contentStyle: "* { background-color: yellow; }"
});
```

or simply:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod").PageMod({
    include: "*",
    contentStyleFile: require("sdk/self").data.url("my-styles.css")
});
```

and then create **data/my-styles.css** file containing:

```
* { backgound-color: yellow: }
```

Answer (score 0):

Access to the DOM from content scripts is somewhat limited, in particular if the page it is accessing modifies the DOM from JS. This is why we currently still provide direct access in content scripts via the unsafeWindow variable. If you try this, does it work?

```
unsafeWindow.jQuery('*').css('background-color', 'yellow');
```